# Where the combobox bound items are coming from?

Tags: wpf, winforms, combobox, datasource, reference-type

May be it's a silly (or more than trivial) kinda question, but it seems i just don't know the answer. Here's the case -

1. I assigned a `UserList` as the `ItemsSource` of a combobox. So what i did essentially is assigning a reference type to another.
2. I cleared the `UserList`. So now i get the `Count` of the `ItemsSource` 0 as well.
3. I still get the items present in my combobox. And i also can cast the `SelectedItem` of the combobox to a `User` object.

Here's the complete code -

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<User> _userList;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _userList = new List<User>()
                                  {
                                      new User() {Id = 1, Name = "X"},
                                      new User() {Id = 2, Name = "Y"},
                                      new User() {Id = 3, Name = "Z"}
                                  };
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.comboBox1.ItemsSource = _userList;
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _userList.Clear();

        /* ItemsSource is cleared as well*/
        IEnumerable userList = this.comboBox1.ItemsSource;

        /*I can still get my User*/
        User user = this.comboBox1.SelectedItem as User;
    }
}
```

So, where the items are coming from? What actually happens under-the-hood when i make such binding? Does the control have some kind of cache? It's a royal pain to realize not having such basic ideas. Can anybody explain the behind-the-scene detail?

**EDIT :** I wrote the code in WPF, but i have the same question for WinForms `Combobox`.

**EDIT :** Doesn't a combobox display its items from it's in-memory `Datasource`? When that datasource contains 0 items, how does it display the items?

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?  It can't be both!

Comment: @DanPuzey: It is a `Combobox` in general, and how it still holds the items after clearing it's datasource.

Comment: WPF and WinForms comboboxes are completely different implementations and don't handle data or binding in the same way.  I don't *think* the WinForms combobox has ItemsSource, so I'd guess this is WPF?

Comment: @DanPuzey: yes i wrote the code in WPF, but i have the same question in case of WinForms

Comment: You need to make it clear in your question that this is the case - your posted code isn't valid WinForms.  (ComboBox in WinForms doesn't have the ItemsSource property, for starters.)  I would suggest that you either post comparable code for WinForms, or restrict your question suitably.  If you assume that the answer is the same between WinForms and WPF, you will only add to your confusion, because they are quite different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set an `ItemsSource` of any `ItemsControl` it copies the ref to the list into its `Items` property. Then it subscribes to the `OnCollectionChanged` event, and creates a `CollectionView` object. So, on the screen you can see that collectionView.

as I have found in source code `ItemCollection` holds two lists:

```
internal void SetItemsSource(IEnumerable value)
    {
      //checks are missed
      this._itemsSource = value;
      this.SetCollectionView(CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultCollectionView((object) this._itemsSource, this.ModelParent));
    }
```

**How could you get SelectedItem?**

This is my assumption from quick look into the source code:

`ItemsControl` has a collection of "views" and each `View` sholud store a ref to the item (`User` instance), because it has to draw data on the screen. So, when you call SelectedItem it returns a saved ref.

**Upd about references**

Assume there is an `User` instance. It has the adress  **123** in memory. There is a list. It stores references. One of them is **123**.

When you set an `ItemsSource` `ItemsControl` saves a reference to the list, and creates a Views collection. Each view stores a references to an item. One view stores an address **123**.

Then you cleared a list of users. Now list doesn't contains any references to `Users`. But in memory there is an adrress 123 and there is an instance of `User` by this adress. Garbage Collector doesn't destroy it, because View has a reference to it.

When you get `SelectedItem` it returns User instance from the **123** adress.

```
var user = new User();

var list = new List<User>();
list.Add(user);

list.Clear();
Console.WriteLine(list.Count()); //prints 0 - list is empty

Console.WriteLine(user == null); //prints false. - user instance is sill exists;
```

Comment: Anton, please see the EDIT. i thought it should better be with the question itself than in a comment.

Comment: On the screen you can see a "view" of your items. ComboBox doesn't know that it have to refresh itself.

Comment: Anton is right. ComboBox has no way of knowing that the contents of List<> has changed. Either assign a new empty List to ItemsSource, or better use an ObservableCollection as Anton suggests.

Comment: @AntonSizikov: If it copies the references then there is my question. They all refer to the same memory location, and i just cleared them. And if it's only the "view" that holds the items then how am i able to cast the `SelectedItem` back to `User` in code?

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: actually i don't *need* to clear the `ComboBox`, i'm trying to understand why it doesn't get cleared, and how it holds the items?

Comment: @NerotheZero: Imagine you were implementing the combo yourself. When someone set your ItemsSource property, you would iterate through it and draw each item on the screen. If the client code then changed the contents in some way, how would you know? All you have is a reference that hasn't changed. The only way would be to constantly re-iterate the collection which would be hugely inefficient.

Comment: @NerotheZero: see my new answer for some clarification on your new question.

Comment: @NerotheZero added some details

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: I'll request you to post an answer elaborating what you mean, please. i don't understand how the reference is not changed after i called `Clear` on `UserList`. they refer to the same memory location, right? and as i commented to Anton, if it's only items drawn on the view how am i being able to cast an item back to `User`?

Comment: @NerotheZero did I answered your last question?

Comment: @AntonSizikov: you're always saying it to be reference, as in "it copies the ref to the list" and "each View sholud store a ref to the item". if it is a reference ( which is nothing but a memory address), then there's no item in there, cuz i just cleared it through another reference, the `_userList`. am i wrong?

Comment: @AntonSizikov: thanks a lot for your help. can you give anything where i can find more on this "copying the ref to the list into its `Items` property" thing?

Comment: What do you want to see? It just saves passed collection.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your comment to @GazTheDestroyer ("... why it doesn't get cleared, and how it holds the items?")

In WPF, when you set the `ItemsSource` property of an `ItemsControl`, the control will wrap the list of items in a `CollectionView`, which is a collection type optimised for use by the UI framework.  This `CollectionView` is assigned to the `Items` property of the control and is what the display-drawing code actually works from.  As you see, this collection is entirely separate of the object you originally assigned to `ItemsSource`, and so there is no propogation of changes from one to the other.  This is why the items are still in the control when you clear the original list: the control is ignoring the original list, and has its own list that contains your objects.

It's for this reason that an `ItemsSource` value needs to raise events - specifically `INotifyCollectionChanged.NotifyCollectionChanged` - so that the control knows to refresh the `Items` list.  `ObservableCollection` implements this interface and raises the correct event, and so the functionality works as expected.

It's hugely important to note that this is *nothing* like what happens in WinForms, which is why I've been pressing you for the clarification.

**EDIT:** To clarify, there is no "deep copy."  The code that is happening is similar in principle to the following:

```
private List<object> myCopy;

public void SetItemsSource(List<object> yourCopy)
{
     myCopy = new List<object>();
     foreach (var o in yourCopy)
     {
         myCopy.Add(o);
     }
}
```

Once this code has run, there's only one copy of every item in your list.  But each of the items is in both of the lists.  If you change, clear or otherwise manipulate `yourCopy`, `myCopy` knows nothing about it.  You cannot "destroy" any of the objects that are within the list my clearing `yourCopy` - all you do is release your own reference to them.

Comment: are you saying is the `ItemsControl` perform a *Deep Copy* on the object assigned to it's `ItemsSource`, not just points to its reference, or "copies the ref to the list", as Anton mentioned ? cuz only that could make sense of this behavior.

Comment: your "...this collection is entirely separate of the object you originally assigned to ItemsSource, and so there is no propogation of changes from one to the other..." indicates something like deep copy takes place here.

Comment: No, it's not a deep copy, just a reference copy.  If you pass me an object `A` and I write `object b = A` then I have my own reference to your object.  If you subsequently remove `A` from a list that I know nothing about, it has no effect on me at all.  Clearing your list doesn't do anything to `A` but remove a reference to it.

Comment: +1 for that the code in EDIT was helpful to correct my view towards list of reference type. thanks a lot :) and where can i find some more on this wrapping the list of items in a `CollectionView` and assigning it to `Items`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using WPF:

`List<User>` doesn't fire any event that the UI will recognise to refresh itself.  If you use `ObservableCollection<User>` instead, your code will work.

The key difference is that `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, which allows the UI to recognise that the content of the collection has changed, and thus refresh the content of the `ComboBox`.

(Note that this *does not* work in WinForms.  In WinForms you can set the `DataSource` property of the control, but the same *ObservableCollection* trick does not work here.)

Answer (score 0):

When you set a collection reference to `ItemsControl`, all the combo gets is a reference, that it knows is enumerable.

It will enumerate the reference and display the items. Whether it does a deep copy or shallow copy is irrelevant, all it has is a reference (memory address effectively).

If you change your collection in some way, the combo has no way of knowing unless you tell it somehow. The reference (address) hasn't changed, everything looks the same to the combo. You seem to be thinking that the object is somehow "live" and the combo can watch the memory changing or something? This isn't the case. All it has is a reference that it can enumerate over. The contents can change but without some trigger the combo doesn't know that, and so will sit doing nothing.

`ObservableCollection` is designed to overcome this. It implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` that fires events when it changes, so the Combo knows that it must update its display.